# Is My Perspective Math Wrong?

Tags: c, opengl, matrix-multiplication

Whenever I try to utilize my glmxLoadPerspective function, nothing is displayed. HOWEVER, my glmxLoadOrtho function displays fine. Is my math wrong? Relevant code (unrelated bits truncated) below:

(APP_WIDTH = 1000, APP_HEIGHT = 1000)

Usage:

```
glmxMatrix ortho;
glmxGenMatrix(&ortho, GLMX_4X4); //This simply loads the identity matrix.
glmxLoadPerspective(&ortho, 45.0f, APP_WIDTH / APP_HEIGHT, 1.0f, 10.0f); //Implementation below.

glmxMatrix modelview;
glmxGenMatrix(&modelview, GLMX_4X4); //Same as above.

const GLfloat verts[] = {
   //verts
   100.0f, 100.0f, -3.0f, 1.0f,
   200.0f, 200.0f, -3.0f, 1.0f,
   100.0f,  200.0f, -3.0f, 1.0f,
   200.0f,  100.0f, -3.0f, 1.0f,
   //colors
   1.0f, 0.3f, 0.4f, 0.5f,
   0.5f, 0.1f, 0.4f, 0.3f,
   0.0f,  1.0f, 0.5f, 0.6f,
   0.0f,  1.0f, 0.5f, 0.6f,
};

glmxMultMatrix(&ortho, &modelview);
```

Frustrum func:

```
glmxvoid glmxLoadFrustrum(glmxMatrix* matrix, glmxfloat left, glmxfloat right, glmxfloat bottom,
    glmxfloat top, glmxfloat near, glmxfloat far){
if(matrix -> mx_type != GLMX_4X4){GLMX_ERROR = GLMX_NOT_4X4; return;}
matrix -> mx_data[0] = (2.0f * near) / (right - left);
matrix -> mx_data[1] = 0.0f;
matrix -> mx_data[2] = 0.0f;
matrix -> mx_data[3] = 0.0f;
matrix -> mx_data[4] = 0.0f;
matrix -> mx_data[5] = (2.0f * near) / (top - bottom);
matrix -> mx_data[6] = 0.0f;
matrix -> mx_data[7] = 0.0f;
matrix -> mx_data[8] = (right + left) / (right - left);
matrix -> mx_data[9] = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
matrix -> mx_data[10] = (-far - near) / (far - near);
matrix -> mx_data[11] = -1.0f;
matrix -> mx_data[12] = 0.0f;
matrix -> mx_data[13] = 0.0f;
matrix -> mx_data[14] = -(2.0f * near) * far / (far - near);
matrix -> mx_data[15] = 0.0f;
}
```

Perspective func:

```
glmxvoid glmxLoadPerspective(glmxMatrix* matrix, glmxfloat fovy, glmxfloat aspect, glmxfloat near,
    glmxfloat far){
glmxfloat ymax = near * tanf(fovy * GLMX_PI / 360.0f), xmax = ymax * aspect;
glmxLoadFrustrum(matrix, -xmax, xmax, -ymax, ymax, near, far);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're putting the x,y asymmetry offsets (8 and 9) in the 3rd column which means they are multiplied with z. I believe 8,9 should be move to 12 and 13.